# What is the correct way to access a filepath in Java?

Tags: java

I am receiving a FileNotFoundException when I try to write to a file, but other classes I use can read from files in the same path. Below is an example where I can read from a file in my resources fine:

```
newMap = false;
    int numTilesAcross;
    BufferedImage tileset;
    String testMapPath = "/Resources/Maps/testmap.map";
    String testTileSetPath = "/Resources/Tilesets/testtileset.gif";
    String itemsPath = "/Resources/Sprites/items.gif";
    //Uses specified file as input, then transforms file contents into a 2D array "map"
    try {

        InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(testMapPath);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

        numCols = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        numRows = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        map = new int[numRows][numCols];
        width = numCols * tileSize;
        height = numRows * tileSize;

        String delims = "\\s+";
        for (int row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            String[] tokens = line.split(delims);
            for (int col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
                map[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[col]);
                //System.out.println(map[row][col]);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

However, in another part of my project I try to write to a different file (same thing applies is I try to write to the file I used previously) the file path cannot be found, as shown below:

```
public void saveItemLocations(){
    String itemLocationPath = "/Resources/Items/itemLocations.txt";

    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(itemLocationPath))){
        bw.write("test");
   } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the file structure for my project:
[image: This is the file structure for my project]

Comment: instead of using `/` you will need \\

Comment: __getClass().getResourceAsStream(testMapPath)__ causes the difference. "Root" is different in both cases. You are not able to write to your _jar_ file so easy.

Comment: Keep in mind there is a very big difference between a "resource" and a "file" on the file system. Resources are typically contained in jar, war and ear files. They are readable as resources, but definitely NOT writable. Whereas a file in the file system is both readable and writable. It *appears* that you are attempting to write to a resource.

Comment: Using Class.getResource() uses the classloader, not file IO, to read "files". The path is the path from one of the roots of the classpath (i.e. it's a package path). The classloader typically loads resources from inside the jar file of your app, not from arbitrary locations on the file system. And those resources are read-only. File IO is completely different. It expects a path on your file system.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I still get the same error with \\

Comment: then use the full filepath

Comment: @JBNizet So how would I access the file to write to? I would like it to use a file that is within the project

Comment: You first need to think of your application not as a development project on your developer machine, but as an application deployed on a user computer. Where will the user find those files? How will you install the application? Are those files part of the application, and thus meant to be read only, or are they data that the user creates and modifies?

Answer (score 1):

Your `FileNotFoundException` can be resolved by doing something like this:

```
public void saveItemLocations(){
    String itemLocationPath = "/Resources/Items/itemLocations.txt";
    File dir = new File("/Resources/Items");
    dir.mkdirs();  // guarantees the directory hierarchy will be created if needed.

    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(itemLocationPath))){
        bw.write("test");
   } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However note that `/Resources/Items/itemLocations.txt` is located on the file system, it is not a `Resource`.

Keep in mind there is a very big difference between a "resource" and a "file" on the file system. Resources are typically contained in `jar`, `war` and `ear` files. They are readable as resources, but definitely NOT writable. Whereas a file in the file system can be both readable and writable. It *appears* that you are attempting to write to a resource

This [technote](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html) at Oracle may help you better understand the difference between a file and a resource.

Answer (score 0):

The `FileInputStream` class works directly with the underlying file system. If the file in question is not physically present there, it will fail to open it.

The `getResourceAsStream()` method works differently. It tries to locate and load the resource using the ClassLoader of the class it is called on. This enables it to find, for example, resources embedded into jar files.